# Virtualbox - win7 - hard drive virtualisation -dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, windows-7, 15.10

I'm dualbooting win7 with ubuntu for some time now.

My main os is ubuntu, however for work purposes i need windows now and then...

As I'm always booting in ubuntu, I have a win7 virtualmachine as well.

The dualboot win7 i use for gaming but also for presentation and so on.

So there is a clear overlap between stuff stored on the dualboot win7 and the virtualmachine, however there is no way to link both.

I know in virtualbox you can load a physical partition as virtualmachine, however for win7 there are licensing problems rendering this solution as impossible,
Therefore I was thinking to play around with partitions. A data partition could be shared between the dualboot and the VM. 
But is this also possible with a software partition?

Or are there betere ideas to avoid this kind of redundant data storage?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Use a folder in the shared partition or Windows 7 partition as shared folder?

Comment: i know how sharing between guest and host works. my questions is how do avoid to much overlap (or thus sharing) between the dualboot win7 and the virtual machine with win7.... what is possible for data(quiet straightforward) but what with software ...

Comment: @user77407 What happens when you install programs to the shared folder on your real Windows, back it up, and then install in VirtualBox in the shared folder? Does that not work? I am not sure what problems might occur because of the different registry entries, but I would be very interested what happens if you try.

Comment: So you would suggest to reinstall the software (but actually overwrite it) on the shared folder? In the hope they end up in the registry of both setups? I'll give that a try, for sure... but maybe somebody can comment before I start?